# Xades4j with custom commitments types

Tags: xades4j

I will need to set customs commitments types (with xades4j, of course).

I had a look to the lib and I got the feeling that is not possible to do so.
The commitments type are finals.

```
.withCommitmentType( AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty commitment )
And AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty  is a final class.
The same for the individual commitments.
```

Is my interpretation correct?

Does it make sense to extend this possibility in xades4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a way to specify `CommitmentTypeQualifiers` as defined in section 7.2.6 of XAdES? Or just need to change the commitment type identifier? In case it's the latter and the identifier is an URI, both `AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty` and `CommitmentTypeProperty` have a constructor you can use. IF not, you're correct.

Supporting arbitrary "untyped" parameters on the commitment indication properties is not easy on the current architecture. I have to see if it would be feasible using some of the existing extensibility points or using another approach. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Luís, 
I think that at the moment the pair uri and description is enough... honestly, I don't have the requirements. I know that the commitments with be specified in a policy file (that I don't have). I doing preliminary work. Thanks for your answer.